# ¿Cómo navegar entre ventanas(JFrame) o JPanel en java?

Tags: java

Estoy usando netbeans 8.0.2.

Actualmente tengo 3 JFrame los cuales están vinculados de forma que al dar clic en uno se cierra el otro JFrame  y hasta ahí todo funciona bien. El problema viene en el efecto que hace el Jframe al cerrarse, ya que se cierra toda la ventana y es muy notorio el cambio de ventana, la cuestion seria como hacer para que en vez de que se cerrase el frame, apareciera el otro frame en la misma ventana como si se escondiera un panel y apareciera otro arriba del mismo.

Ahorita tengo este codigo para navegar entre frames*

```
    NewJFrame2 open = new NewJFrame2();
    open.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
```

Con el código anterior navego de una ventana(NewJFrame) a otra ventana(NewJFrame2) pero en vez de esconderse se cierra toda la ventana y abre otra ventana.

Comment: ¿Ya probate usando `CardLayout`?

Comment: Un `JFrame` es una ventana por lo que no puedes cambiar un `JFrame` por otro sin cerrar el primero o esconderle. Una posible solución seria tener 3 `JPanel`, uno por cada `JFrame` y ya decides cual mostrar con `setVisible(false)`y con `setVisible(true)`en el `JFrame` principal. Cada `JPanel`deberia tener lo mismo que los `JFrame`y de esta manera podrias cambiar de uno a otro en la misma ventana

Comment: se puede poner un jPanel sobre otro Jpanel?